# How to get country from (intl-tel-input) jquery on a django project with crispy form?

Tags: jquery, django, django-crispy-forms

I have this form from a Django project that essentially uses crispy forms;

```
class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = (
            'proposal',
            'name',
            'email',
            'phone',
            'birth_date',
            'nationality',
            'occupation',
            'identification_document_type',
            'rg_rne',
            'issuing_body',
            'cpf',
            'father_name',
            'mother_name',
            'marital_status',
            'spouse',
            'public_person',
            'buyer_type',
        )
```

From this model:

```
class Buyer(BaseBuyer, BuyerModelMixin):
    name = models.CharField(_("nome"), max_length=300)
    email = models.EmailField(_("email"))
    phone = PhoneNumberField(
        _("celphone"),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    birth_date = models.DateField(_("birth_date_"))
```

How can I customize this form.html to include the jQuery intl-tel-input library?
I've made some attempts, but I haven't been successful. I believe I'm making a mistake with the tag inside the HTML.
I wasn't successful with these attempts.
Even when importing via CDN, I wasn't successful.

```
{% block contents %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form id="form-container" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}

                        <div id="form-document" style="display: block">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Buyer's Docs {{ buyer.name }}</h4>
                            <b>Pending docs</b>
                            {% for pending in pending_documents %}
                                <li>{{ pending }}</li>
                            {% endfor %}
```

I'm using crispy_forms and I'm having difficulty changing only the phone field.
I made these attempts, in general, just to provide examples.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="buyer.static.css.input.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#phone-input').intlTelInput({
    });
  });
</script>
```

on form.html
I kept it like this in the HTML file to try customizing the phone field.

```
{{ form.phone|as_crispy_field|add_class:"phone-field" }}
```

Comment: What do you git in the browser console if you run `$("#phon-input").length`?

Comment: show me one: '1'

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It doesn't return an error, actually I'm just not able to style the 'phone' element with the jQuery library. 
I'm not sure how to select the 'phone' field in form.html using crispy.

Comment: Can you look into the generated HTML by right-clicking on your phone field, clicking on inspect and pasting the relevant part of the HTML into the question?